# Need a minimal circuit to obtain 5V from discrete 5V to 20V (5V, 9V 12V, 15V or 20V) input

Tags: ldo, linear-regulator, usb-c, power-delivery

I have a `Vin` that can cycle between a set of discrete levels: 5V, 9V, 12V, 15V or 20V (a USB-C PD source.)

The `Vin` will be changed depending on the valves' voltage requirements. But, I also need a stable 5V `Vout` for a MCU.

If I simply feed the `Vin` into a 7805 or AMS1117-5V, then the `Vout` might be too low when the `Vin` is at 5V.

Inspired by Swagatam's "Zero Drop LDO Solar Charger" article, I came up with the following (see screenshot).

My goal is to have a stable 5V for different voltage levels of `Vin`. `Vin` should be at 5V most of the time. `Vin` can be a battery, so I would like to avoid buck-boost just to get the 5V for efficiency and heat considerations.

My attempt uses `M1` to pass `Vin` as-is, when it is at 5v (`G` of `M1` is controlled by `D2`, a Zener Diode with `Vpeak` of 5v). When `Vin` is higher than 5V, `M1` will not pass, and `M2` pass `Vin` to a regulator and output 5V.

Would the circuit work in practice? Why or why not?

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Just use a buck-boost converter with a wide input range. A linear regulator dropping up to 15 volts sounds like a recipe for magic smoke to me.

Comment: *My goal is to have a stable 5v for different voltage levels of Vin.* this circuit is not going to do that, M1 is bypassing the 7805 so you might get more than 5 V at the output. There are buck-boost modules you can buy that can convert voltages between 3 V and 30 V to 5 V so why are you re-inventing what already exists?

Comment: @Hearth:  A 7805 dropping 15V is what it was designed for.  Actually doing it requires a heat sink, but doesn't involve magic smoke.

Comment: @JRE I'm just not a fan of linear regulators, I suppose. Good if you need to reduce ripple while lowering the voltage by one or two volts, but not so good if you want to use high voltage differentials. I work with moderately high currents a lot, in the tens of amps, and a 7805 would not be happy with that.

Comment: @Hearth and @Bimpelrekkie, I like to avoid buck-boost because `Vin` might be a battery source (edited the question to clarify). Majority of the time, the whole system and the MCU will be idle and running at ~50uA.

Comment: @Thomas-BeeDesk:  The buck-boost will be more efficient than the 7805.  The 7805 consumes about 5 milliamperes all by itself - all the time, even without a load.  Not to mention that the 7805 drops the voltage by generating heat.

Comment: @JRE, yes, but `Vin` is usually at 5v. Let's assume 7805 is replaced with something more efficient (I picked 7805, simply because CircuitLab have it on the component palette and many people immediate know it means a regulator.)

Comment: A switching regulator with an enable pin can drop its consumption to microamperes when in standby.

Comment: @JRE. It is a good idea, I can replace `M2 and 7805` with a switching regulator with an enable pin.

Comment: There are switching regulators using PMOS switch that allow 100% duty cycle and Vout almots equal to Vin.

Comment: @Thomas-BeeDesk you can really replace your whole circuit with a switching regulator, and be done with it. A buck conductor in constant transmission mode is actually just a transistor used as a closed switch. Done!

Comment: @bobflux can you think of an inexpensive part? I saw boost regulator that has `Vin` and `Vout` being very close together, but buck seems to be a trade off between current and drop voltage. My MCU might be ESP32 which consumes quite some current when wifi is initially begin turn on (but only for brief period).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, what is an example of the part? AMS1117v5 dropped about 0.9v which is too much. 7805 is nice that it doesn't need any other component.

Comment: That's incorrect, Thomas. Both need external capacitors. And the 7805 drops way more than an 1117. And neither are switch mode converters. Go to your large component distributor's website, click through to the step-down switch mode regulators and select one from the list. Literally thousands to choose from.

Comment: How much current do you need for the MCU, and how much current does the valve consume at 5V, 9V, 12V, 15V and 20V? By 'valve' do you mean a device for controlling the passage of fluid or air through a pipe?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, yes valves is a solenoid valve for fluid. It takes ~1.5A at 12v. MCU takes up to 300mA. But then I also hoping I can charge a small backup Lipo.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do it is with a buck-mode switching regulator set for 5 V output. At input voltages of 9V, 12V, 15V or 20V it will step the voltage down to 5 V. At 5 V it will simply pass the input voltage through, providing it can do 100% PWM and has a PMOS pass transistor.

In 'pass through' mode current flows continuously through the pass transistor and the inductor, so for low voltage drop they need to have low resistance. This can be assured by using a regulator circuit which has much greater maximum current output than you need. One example of a suitable module is the [XL4015](https://components101.com/modules/xl4015-dc-dc-converter-module), which only drops ~0.05 V with 5 V in and a 300 mA load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am really new to this. Does XL4015 has a built-in "pass through" already? Or, I need to build it around XL4015?

Comment: Yes, it's built-in.